# Specifying download dir with yum downloadonly

Tags: yum, rhel5

I'm trying to run the following:

yum reinstall glibc --downloadonly --downloaddir=/root/dependencies/

But it keeps giving me an error that --downloaddir is not a valid option though I've seen others use it around the web. I'm using RHEL Workstation 5.5. Is there another way to specify the downloaddir?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first install yumdownloader

`yum install yumdownloader`